# Perform join only on subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables:

- 1st is `DIAGNOZY` which contains columns: `year`, `ID`, `gendre`, `birthday`, `ICZ` which is ID of health care provider, `diagnosis_code` and `date`. Every row is doctors record for a patient. There is several records for each ID from same/different doctor (ICZ) with same/different diagnosis.
- 2nd table `PACIENT_SEKVENCE_DETAIL` is table for `ID`s which have a special drug, number of types of drugs they have been using before, date of the first prescription (`date_first`) and date of prescription of the special drug `(date_special)`.

I would like to choose only patients who have the date of diagnose from `DIAGNOZY` on the same day or later than the `date_special` in `PACIENT_SEKVENCE_DETAIL` and have only this one diganose for the whole time (no multiple diagnosis).

The table I would like to have at the end would have two columns: `ID` and `DG` (diagnosis) and there would be distinct patients who meet the stated condition - so every patient would be there just once as he would not have more than one diagnosis.

My code looks like that:

```
select t1.ID, diagnosis_code as DG
from (
    select d.ID as ID, count(distinct diagnosis_code) as count_dg
    from DIAGNOZY d join PACIENT_SEKVENCE_DETAIL s on d.ID=s.ID
    where d.date>=s.date_special
    group by d.ID
    having count(distinct diagnosis_code)=1) t1
join DIAGNOZY f on t1.ID=f.ID
group by t1.ID, f.diagnosis_code
```

However it returns all the patients with all diagnosis and completely ignores the conditions in the inner select.

I am very new to SQL and I learn by myself using Internet so pardon my stupidity.

DIAGNOZY TABLE:

```
year ID gendre  birth_date ICZ  diagnosis_code date
2012    35902587895 M   2000    94618000    L400    2012-06-11  
2013    35902587895 M   2000    94619000    L400    2013-02-04  
2012    35902587895 M   2000    94618000    L400    2012-07-11  
2013    35902587895 M   2000    94618000    L400    2013-05-10  
2011    35902591668 M   2000    08009000    L400    2011-09-27  
2015    35902596431 M   2000    89177000    M0800   2015-08-26  
2010    35902612150 M   2000    10194000    M459    2010-01-07
```

PACIET_SEKVENCE_DETAIL

```
ID  date_first date_special nr_types_before 
35902743897 2014-10-20  2014-10-20  0  
35902767371 2016-07-27  2016-07-27  0  
35902767756 2015-09-25  2015-09-25  0  
35902772607 2010-08-04  2010-08-04  0  
35902816112 2013-12-19  2013-12-19  0  
35903616362 2014-10-02  2014-10-02  0  
35903663981 2010-01-06  2010-01-19  1
```

So in the final table there will be only ID and diagnosis_code for people who have only one distinct diagnosis in table DIAGNOZY and are present in the other table, where in nr_types_befor is 0.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I have added sample, hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query all together and your sample data does not come together, you are referencing d.start_data yest only the table with the alias 's' holds all the columns on your where clause.

Comment: I am sorry, I've been changing names of columns to made it more readable and made a mistake while doing that. Is that what you were referring to: 
where d.date>=s.date_special (before where d.date_first>=s.date_special)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.ID, 
    d.diagnosis_code DG     
FROM DIAGNOZY d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT d1.ID FROM 
        DIAGNOZY d1
        INNER JOIN PACIENT_SEKVENCE_DETAIL s ON d1.ID = s.ID 
                        AND s.nr_types_before = 0
    WHERE 
        d1.ID = d.ID
        AND d1.date >= s.date_special
    GROUP BY d1.ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d1.diagnosis_code) = 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need to only have patients that have 1 diagnosis during the whole time. Your code will give me one row for each diagnose a patient has, so there are also patients with multiple diagnosis over the time.